# Interface Segregation Principle - How to call a method that is defined in a separate interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, polymorphism

So we have had an interface that's been around for a long time.  Let's call it `IFoo`.  It has a lot of methods defined in it, and there are about 10 classes that implement it.

All along, when we need to create an instance of one of those classes, we've used a simple factory pattern:

```
IFoo foo = FooFactory.Create(...);
```

Then, of course, we have access to all of the methods defined in IFoo:

```
foo.Method1();
foo.Method2();
etc.
```

But now, we have some methods that need to be in *some* of the ten classes, but not all of them. So in keeping with the Interface Segregation Principle, it's my understanding that we should create a new Interface: `IBar`.

So the classes that need the methods that will be defined in IBar will look like this:

```
public class something: IFoo, IBar
{
     ...
}
```

So far so good. But what I'm unsure of how is how to then access these methods.  Because when we use the same factory method:

```
IFoo foo = FooFactory.Create(...);
```

`foo` does not have any of the methods that are in `IBar`.

The factory method looks like this (this is a scaled down version to make things easier for this post):

```
public static IFoo Create(string className)
{
     Type type = Type.GetType(className);
     return (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

So anyway, I'm unclear on how to modify all of this to have access to the methods in `IBar` as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, and I fully admit that this is a principle I don't fully understand!

Comment: /\ Totally get that! Is it possible to create a factory method that returns an object is that IS both IFoo and IBar, so that it would have access to all the methods in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just try to use [type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator), your code will not be resistant to changes and may breaks during [refactoring](https://refactoring.guru/extract-class). In order to choose a solution you need to answer the following questions:

- What is `IFoo` and `IBar`? Why do you separate this interfaces and when should they be used? It's questions about motivation to use [interface-segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). If you have 2 really different use cases it's OK but you should not to use it just to comply with the rules. It's ok to have interface with many methods. if you decide that `IFoo` and `IBar` are in fact one interface then just combine them to `IFooBar` interface.
- OK. We decided that we really have two interfaces. Next question is why class Something implements both of these interfaces? Does it breaks [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)? If so then you need to separate this class to `class Foo : IFoo` and `class Bar : IBar` and creates new factory for class `Bar` to use it in cases you need to call `BarMethod()`. You may have duplicate code problem or reusing shared resource problem.
- If you have duplicate code problem so just use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance) to solve it.

```
    public class SomeBase { /* common code */ }
    public class Foo : SomeBase, IFoo { /* IFoo impementation */ }
    public class Bar : SomeBase, IBar { /* IBar impementation */ }
```

- If you have reusing shared resource problem so can solve it with [dependency injection](https://www.codementor.io/mrfojo/c-with-dependency-injection-k2qfxbb8q). For example, you'll add `BarFactory` and both `FooFactory` and `BarFactory` uses `SharedResourceRepository` that stores and allow access to the shared resources. If you use IoC-Container, then the problem is solved by its configuration.
- OK. We decided that we really have one class. Next question is why do you need to retrieve an instance of `IFoo` to use its `IBar` methods? It definitely breaks object oriented design and each solution will only be a hack. You should create `BarFactory` and solve single instance problem with [Singletone](https://refactoring.guru/en/design-patterns/singleton), IoC-containers or so on.